# Error with cursor and SQLite in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have an error with a cursor when I'm reading a database :

```
04-07 18:11:25.672: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5801): android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=666 (# cursors opened by this proc=666)
```

It happens on the line

```
cursor.getCount()
```

The entire file is 8kb, it has 32 lines, but IDs go from 737 to 768, is the problem from there?

(I have noticed that if ID is below 600, there are no problems)

Comment: More code would be helpful... the error message seems to indicate you are opening a lot of cursors at once.

Answer (score 0):

(Question answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved the problem. My code was :

```
public News getNewsWithID(int id){
        Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_NEWS, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_ASSO, COL_DATE, COL_HEURE, COL_TYPE, COL_TITRE, COL_CONTENU, COL_SERVEURID}, COL_ID +"='"+ id +"'" , null, null, null, null);
        return cursorToNews(c);
    }
```

> I changed to :

```
public News getNewsWithID(int id){
        Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_NEWS, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_ASSO, COL_DATE, COL_HEURE, COL_TYPE, COL_TITRE, COL_CONTENU, COL_SERVEURID}, COL_ID +"='"+ id +"'" , null, null, null, null);
        News temp = cursorToNews(c);
        c.close();
        return temp;
    }
```

I thought that the cursor was closed on onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

You should really be closing the cursor in a `finally` block, to ensure that it's closed even if an exception happens.

```java
public News getNewsWithID(int id){
    Cursor c = bdd.query(TABLE_NEWS, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_ASSO, COL_DATE, COL_HEURE, COL_TYPE, COL_TITRE, COL_CONTENU, COL_SERVEURID}, COL_ID +"='"+ id +"'" , null, null, null, null);
    try {
        return cursorToNews(c);
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
```